# Is this mechanism for the formation of a tosylate correct?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

I've been given this mechanism by my lecturer for the formation of a tosylate. It claims that NEt<sub>3</sub> is needed to remove the hydrogen from the O<sup>+</sup> in the second step. However surely the Cl<sup>-</sup> from TsCl would remove the H and no NEt<sub>3</sub> is needed?

[image]

Comment: No, $\ce{Cl-}$ is a much worse base than $\ce{NEt3}$.

Answer (score 4):

No, $\ce{Cl-}$ will not remove the $\ce{H+}$ because it is not basic enough. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{Cl-}$'s conjugate acid ($\ce{HCl}$) is $-7$. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{NEt3}$'s conjugate acid ($\ce{HNEt3+}$) is $10.75$ ([source](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf)). This means that $\ce{HCl}$ almost completely dissociates in solution, and is very unlikely to form $\ce{HCl}$ molecules. $\ce{NEt3}$, on the other hand, is much more basic and will easily pick up the $\ce{H+}$.

Also the mechanism is incorrect. A lot of the arrows are wrong. See [here](http://studydroid.com/imageCards/10/7e/card-33798425-back.jpg) (pyridine serves the same function as $\ce{NEt3}$):

[image: Tosyl ester formation]

Comment: [pKa of Et3NH+: 10.75 in water](http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf) I'm fairly sure that website got it mixed up. All the pKb values cited (including the anilines, pyridine etc.) are actually pKaH values

Comment: This sulfur-oxygen bond movement is... eh.